# Nginx ssl - Passphrase is needed even with key without passphrase

Tags: nginx, ssl

I generated new key using this,
(I wanted start nginx without passphrase)

> openssl rsa -in server.key.org -out server.key

and everything looks fine, but when I try restart nginx it still ask for a pem passphrase(and even I typed the key it still ask for the passphrase...),
default config in sites-available is fine.

why pem is needed then?

greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PEM is a file that contains both the key and certificate data. The order is important, 
KEY first,
CERT Second.

It's possible that you did not update the PEM file accordingly.